# Replace string in an imported CSV file / multiple conditions

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to import a CSV file and then replace the string `domain\username` AND the string `domain\login` with the word `SSO`.

I know that replacing only `domain\username` would be:

```
(Get-Content $ImportCPUFile) |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '"domain\username"', '"sso"' } |
    Out-File -FilePath CSV-cleaned.csv -Force -Encoding ascii
```

But how to make an OR statement in the `ForEach-Object` function for `domain\username` and `domain\login`? I tried:

```
(Get-Content $ImportCPUFile) |
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '"domain\username"', '"sso"' -or $_ -replace '"domain\login"', '"sso"'} |
    Out-File -FilePath CSV-cleaned.csv -Force -Encoding ascii
```

But it returns only TRUE statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try RegEx or '|'

```
(Get-Content $ImportCPUFile) |
ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '"domain\\username"|"domain\\login"', '"sso"' } |
Out-File -FilePath CSV-cleaned.csv -Force -Encoding ascii
```